# GCP and ServiceAccount hierarchical scope

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am still confuse about hierarchical scope when creating a service account into two  differents folder with no direct link. Or more simply if I create two different folder from the organization root folder can a service account assigned to a project within one of the folder could have admin access to the other ?

Thanks a lot for your enlightment.

Jonathan.

Answer (score 1):

Identities (user accounts, service accounts, groups, domains) are assigned at the Organization level, Folder level, or Project level (and individual resources). These identities have rights only at the level they are assigned. These rights are inherited at subsequent child levels.

For example, an identity assigned only within a project has no rights for other projects or higher up (Folder, Organization).

Another example, an identity assigned at the Folder level has rights at the folder and all projects that are children of that Folder including other child Folders.

If you view the Organization at the top and Folders at the next level down, an identity assigned at one level only has rights to the resource and the children of that resource. Rights/permissions are not inherited up or sideways.

Comment: I am agree this is what documentation is saying. Nonetheless for service account since they are created within a project, does that mean It can be assigned then to any level ? It is pretty confusing.

Comment: @JonathanChevalier - Identities can be assigned anywhere including other accounts (organization, folder, project, resource). A service account is just another identity.